# Django Filter if field is not None

Tags: python, django

I have a model where I can set `expire_date`.
I want to filter the model and when there's a expire_date set it should filter if the expire_date is lower than now.

I tried it to do with Case and When but I can't filter in a When function, can I?

```
News.objects.all().annotate(is_expired=Case(When(F("expire_date") != None, then=False if F("expire_date") <= datetime.now() else True))).filter(is_expired=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, the `condition` should be a `Q` object, or you specify the condition through the named parameters:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Q, When

News.objects.annotate(
    is_expired=Case(
        When(
            condition=Q(expire_date__isnull=True) | Q(expire_date__gte=datetime.now()),
            then=True
        ),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).filter(is_expired=False)
```

You can not write Python code with ternary operators, etc. and then hope that automagically it is transformed into an SQL query.

That being said, here you simply filter on the annotation, so you can just write this as:

```
News.objects.filter(Q(expire_date__isnull=True) | Q(expire_date__gte=datetime.now()))
```

this thus will include all `New`s objects with `expire_date` equal to `NULL`, or where `expire_date` is greater than or equal to `datetime.now()`. The logic in your answer did not make much sense, since it would annotate `is_expired` with all non-null `expire_date`s that are null, or where `expre_date` is *less* than the current time.